# Is it possible to construct order types using sets?

Tags: set-theory, relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations, ordinals

It's possible to construct a "function" $f$ from the class of well-ordered sets to the class of all sets where for any well-ordered sets $A$ and $B$, we have $f(A)=f(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are order-isomorphic.  (I put function in scare quotes because the domain and codomain are proper classes.) [Von Neumann's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) of the ordinal numbers achieves this.

My question is, can we generalize this to the order types of all totally ordered sets?  That is, can we construct a "function" $g$ from the class of totally ordered sets to the class of all sets where for any totally ordered sets $A$ and $B$, we have $g(A)=g(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are order-isomorphic?  Of course such a function exists by the axiom of choice, but can we actually define such a function? And if so can we make it so that $g=f$ when restricted to the class of well-ordered sets?

Comment: If you have global choice, sure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But I don't just want to prove the existence of such a function, I want to explicitly construct such a function, akin to von Neumann's construction of the ordinals.

Comment: If you have global choice, simply choose from the set of least rank or something like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila And can you make it so that $g$ restricted to well-ordered sets is equal to $f$?

Comment: Sure... Why not?

Comment: Note that you don't require that $g$ itself actually output a linear order, just that it provide an invariant. In the absence of this further condition, constructing such a $g$ is easy: simply let $g(A)$ be the set of all linear orders isomorphic to $A$ such that no linear order of strictly smaller rank in the cumulative hierarchy is isomorphic to $A$. That is, we just use Scott's trick. And we can modify this to extend $f$ by adding an "if" clause: $g$ behaves as above if $A$ is not a well-ordering, and otherwise sends $A$ to the corresponding ordinal. So you may want to modify your question.